# How to logout using the authts/react-oidc-context library with keycloak authorization server

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

Here is my current implementation with react-router-dom, oidc-client-ts, react-oidc-context with the keycloak authorization server

With the following library versions

```
"oidc-client-ts": "^2.2.4",
"react-oidc-context": "^2.2.2",
```

```
<Route
    path="/protected"
    element={
        <AuthOidcProvider>
            <AuthBarrier>
            <AppLayout />
            </AuthBarrier>
        </AuthOidcProvider>
    }
    >
    <Route path={HOME_PATH} element={<Home />} />
  </Route>
```

The AuthOidcProvider component is used to provide the auth context

```
interface AuthOidcProviderProps {
    children: ReactNode;
}

const AuthOidcProvider: FC<AuthOidcProviderProps> = ({
    children,
}): JSX.Element => {
    // const navigate = useNavigate();

    const oidcConfig = {
        redirect_uri: OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI,
        post_logout_redirect_uri: OAUTH2_POST_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URI,
        silent_redirect_uri: OAUTH2_POST_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URI,
        authority: OAUTH2_AUTHORITY,
        client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
        scope: "openid profile email",
        automaticSilentRenew: true,
        onSigninCallback() {
            // You must provide an implementation of onSigninCallback to oidcConfig to remove the payload
            // from the URL upon successful login.
            // Otherwise if you refresh the page and the payload is still there, signinSilent - which handles renewing your token - won't work.

            console.log("onSigninCallback()");
            window.history.replaceState(
                {},
                document.title,
                window.location.pathname
            );
        },
    };

    return <AuthProvider {...oidcConfig}>{children}</AuthProvider>;
};

export default AuthOidcProvider;
```

The AuthBarrier component handles automatic authentication and blocks unauthenticated users

```
interface AuthBarrierProps {
    children: ReactElement;
}

// Automatically sign-in and silently reestablish your previous session, if you close the tab and reopen the application.
const AuthBarrier: FC<AuthBarrierProps> = ({ children }): JSX.Element => {
    const auth = useAuth();

    // automatically sign-in
    useEffect(() => {
        if (
            !hasAuthParams() &&
            !auth.isAuthenticated &&
            !auth.activeNavigator &&
            !auth.isLoading
        ) {
            auth.signinRedirect();
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [
        auth.isAuthenticated,
        auth.activeNavigator,
        auth.isLoading,
        auth.signinRedirect,
    ]);

    // // inactivity listener
    // useEffect(() => {
    //  // the `return` is important - addAccessTokenExpiring() returns a cleanup function
    //  return auth.events.addAccessTokenExpiring(() => {
    //      console.log("Access token expiring...");
    //      // renew the access token silently
    //      auth.signinSilent();
    //      console.log("Access token renewed.");
    //  });
    //  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    // }, [auth.events, auth.signinSilent]);

    switch (auth.activeNavigator) {
        case "signinSilent":
            console.log("signinSilent");
            return <div>Signing you in...</div>;
        case "signoutRedirect":
            console.log("signoutRedirect");
            return <div>Signing you out...</div>;
    }

    if (auth.isLoading) {
        return <LoadingAnimation />;
    }

    if (auth.error) {
        console.error(auth.error);
        return <LoadingAnimation />;
    }

    if (!auth.isAuthenticated) {
        return <LoadingAnimation />;
    }

    return <Fragment>{children}</Fragment>;
};

export default AuthBarrier;
```

When I try to logout with the **auth.removeUser()**, I am always redirected to the "HOME" page.
In the oidcConfig, the **post_logout_redirect_uri** has no effect

Does anyone have an example to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and solved calling signoutRedirect() after removeUser():

```
const handleLogout = () => {
    auth.removeUser();
    auth.signoutRedirect();
  };
```

This way the browser redirects to the auth server login page.

I used the same URI for post_logout_redirect_uri and redirect_uri.

Hope it helps.